# covariant derivative of the second form with the induced Levi-Civita connectiom

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, connections

In a solution to a question of an exam I found the following claim:

Let $(M,g)$ a Riemannian manifold and let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connnection induced by the metric $g$. Consider $(\overline{M},\overline{g})$ a submanifold of $M$ of codimension $1$, where $\overline{g}$ is the induced metric by $g$. Let $\overline{\nabla}$ be the Levi-Civita connection for $\overline{g}$.
Let $\chi(\overline{M})$ be the space of smooth vector fields on $\overline{M}$.
We can define the second fundamental form $k$ as a $(0,2)$ tensor by defining

$k(X,Y):= -g(\nabla_{X}n,Y) \qquad X,Y \in \chi(\overline{M})$

where $n$ is the vector normal to $\overline{M}$.

Until here everything is fine. The claim is the following:
For $X,Y,Z \in \chi(\overline{M})$

$\nabla_{X}k(Y,Z)= k(\nabla_{X}Y,Z)+ k(Y,\nabla_XZ)=  k(\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y,Z)+ k(Y,\overline{\nabla}_XZ)= \overline{\nabla}_{X}k(Y,Z)$

I Cannot understand the claim. Indeed, it seems to me that they are using a reasoning as follows:

$\nabla_XY= \overline{\nabla}_X Y$

whenever $X,Y \in \chi(\overline{M})$. But as far as I know this is not necessarily true.
The claim needs to be true because it is part of the solution, but I can not understand why.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It suffices to show that the two covariant derivatives differ by a normal vector. Also, the normal vector $n$ is assumed to be unit.

Comment: I do not understand for what purpose it is sufficient

Comment: After looking this more carefully, I suggest you ignore this discussion. There are all sorts of issues with it. For one thing $k$ is a symmetric $2$-tensor on $\overline{M}$, so one can take the covariant derivative of it using only the connection $\overline\nabla$. I don't know what the definition of $\nabla_Xk$ is, and since, whatever it is, it turns out to be equal to $\overline\nabla_Xk$, there's no reason to use it at all.